# Center vertically in tabularx with modified height

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabularx

I would like to :

- center vertically the content in a row
- change the height of the row

Here is an attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1] {m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{4}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{2}{Y|}}
        \hline 
        test & test \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

but it does not work.

What is the best way to handle tables in an easy and highly customisable way? How to to solve the present issue?

Thanks

[image]

---

EDIT: The solution of Zarko does not work, as shown in this MWE: the text is not entered vertically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makecell,tabularx}
\setcellgapes{12pt}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}


\begin{document}
{
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{2}{Y|}}
        \hline
    This is a longer line, this is a longer line, this is a longer line & test \\
        \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- context of your table is not known so i can only guess that you like to have above and below of cells' contents more vertical space, for example 12pt. this can be done (in case, that table hasn't colored rows or columns) with help of `makecell` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makecell,tabularx}
\setcellgapes{12pt}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}


\begin{document}
{
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{2}{Y|}}
        \hline
    test & test \\
        \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{document}
```

**edit:**

- alternative solutionis use `cellspace` pacakge and in cells with multi line content use `\parbox{\linewidth}{...}` (unfortunately `makecell` doesn't work with `m` column types, and `cellspace` has problems with multi lines contents too).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cellspace, tabularx}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{12pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{12pt}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

%------------- show page layout. don't use this in real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|*{2}{S{C{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}}|}
                }
    \hline
test & \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering\lipsum[11]}  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have edited my question because your solution does not work (but this idea and this package are nice!)

Comment: @Colas, see edited answer (btw, my solution works perfectly for one line content :-), so you should first provide correct question and  than complain)

Comment: Yes you’re right. Sorry